# Can't connect to the internet while the TV is connected

Tags: networking, home-networking, tv, smart-tv

At home, I can connect multiple devices (laptops, cell phones, TV) to the internet and it works most of the times on all devices. For some unknown reason though, sometimes I am not able to connect to the internet on my laptop and to fix it, all I have to do is to turn off my TV. It seems as if my TV would be "draining" the whole internet and I am not able to connect on other devices as long as I don't turn the TV off. That happens even with the TV on stand-by mode.

My setup is pretty traditional. I have a modem connect to a wireless switch. All devices connect to the network via wireless, with the exception of the TV, which is connected via Ethernet cable.

Comment: Sounds like you might not have enough IP addresses in your DHCP pool on whatever you are using as your DHCP server.  Typically that's the wireless switch.  Have you checked to make sure you have a large enough pool?

Comment: Your TV's LAN adapter could be defective and bombarding the network with messages, in effect doing a [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).

Comment: Is this part of a iptv service setup? And have you tried connecting the TV to another port in this "wireless switch"?

Answer (score 1):

Your TV's LAN adapter could be defective and bombarding the network with messages.

You would in this case be under an internal
[denial-of-service attack (DoS attack)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @DavidPostill: ??????